# How to get ToDictionary to work in F#?

Tags: c#, linq, f#

I have this C# example, which will create a dictionary of odd and even numbers from an array of integers:

```
int[] values = new int[]
{
    1,
    2,
    3,
    5,
    7
};

Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = 
           values.ToDictionary(key => key, val => (val % 2 == 1) ? "Odd" : "Even");

// Display all keys and values.
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in dictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine(pair);
}
```

Output is:

```
[1, Odd]
[2, Even]
[3, Odd]
[5, Odd]
[7, Odd]
```

I want to do it similarly in F# using ToDictionary, and have this so far:

```
let values = [| 1; 2; 3; 5; 7 |]

let dictionary = values.ToDictionary( ??? )

// Display all keys and values.
for d in dictionary do
    printfn "%d %s" d.Key d.Value
```

But how will I write the logic inside ToDictionary?

Comment: @Jim Garrison: I tried with Daniel's answer, and it worked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
ToDictionary(id, fun v -> if v % 2 = 1 then "Odd" else "Even")
```

Comment: Thanks! So the first parameter must be called "id" then?

Comment: No. `id` is a built-in function that's equivalent to `fun x -> x`. See the [docs on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353607.aspx).

Comment: It works if I use "id" as first parameter. But if I replace your "id" with "fun key -> key" output is no longer correct.

Comment: In this case you have to put `fun key -> key` in parenthesis: `ToDictionary((fun key -> key), fun v -> if v % 2 = 1 then "Odd" else "Even")`

Comment: the reason being that otherwise the compiler assumes your function is returning a tuple rather than that you are passing multiple parameters to `ToDictionary`

Answer (score 14):

You can certainly use `ToDictionary` (and all other LINQ methods) from F#, but sometimes it is more idiomatic to use functions from the F# library.

If I vanted to create this dictionary, I'd use something like this:

```
let values = [| 1; 2; 3; 5; 7 |]
let dictionary = dict [ for v in values -> v, if v % 2 = 1 then "Odd" else "Even" ]
```

Here `dict` is an F# library function that creates a dictionary from tuples containing keys and values (the tuple is created using `,` and so we use `v` as the key and a string as a value).

Comment: To use `dict` you have to add `open ExtraTopLevelOperators`. Also in this case dictionary will be immutable `IDictionary<int, string>`: `Add()`, `Remove()` etc. will throw an exception.

Comment: To get to `Dictionary` instead of `IDictionary` you can use `Dictionary` constructor, example: `new Dictionary<string,obj>( dictionary )`